# How to save value to chrome storage without button?

Tags: javascript, events, google-chrome-extension, event-handling, google-chrome-storage

Need to save input's value of type `text` to `chrome.storage.sync.set` without uses `ok` button.

```
<input id="titleUserTab" type="text">
<input id="urlUserTab" type="text">
```

## Problem

1. Event `change` of text element triggers by lost it focus. In this case, problem is need to button `ok` in order to lost focus.
2. Event `input` of text element triggers by each keyboard's button. Problem is limits of `chrome.storage.sync`:

> `MAX_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_HOUR = 1800` The maximum number of set, remove, or clear operations that can be
>   performed each hour.
>
> `MAX_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_MINUTE = 120` The maximum number of set, remove, or clear operations that can be
>   performed each minute.
>
> [Description](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage#property-sync)

## My solution

In order to `remove` button `ok`, use the `input` event.

And to `save` the values, I added an interval and deleted the handler before the trigger time.

What do you think about this case? Maybe you have your own solution? Thanks for any help.

```
// onload page
function restoreUserTabContext(data) {
    titleUserTab.value = data.title;
    urlUserTab.value = data.url;

    titleUserTab.addEventListener('input', onInputUserTabContext);
    urlUserTab.addEventListener('input', onInputUserTabContext);
}

// handler
function onInputUserTabContext() {
    titleUserTab.removeEventListener('input', onInputUserTabContext);
    urlUserTab.removeEventListener('input', onInputUserTabContext);

    setTimeout(function () {
        let data = {
            title: titleUserTab.value,
            url: urlUserTab.value,
        };

        titleUserTab.addEventListener('input', onInputUserTabContext);
        urlUserTab.addEventListener('input', onInputUserTabContext);

        saveOption('dataUserTab', data);
    }, 4000);
}

function saveOption(key, value) {
    option = {};
    option[key] = value;

    chrome.storage.sync.set(option, function () {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your solution has a 4 seconds window in which there is no **input** listeners added to the two `<input>` elements.

Comment: @Titus This is done on purpose. Otherwise, each new character will trigger this function. As a result, there will be a queue of several calls with one letter each. In the current version, the actual value is taken after 4 seconds.

Comment: @Viewed Check my answer :)

Comment: Where can these limit values be found? It seems like they are no longer visible online...

Comment: @lbragile my cache copy with limit values: https://yadi.sk/i/oK8o6KYW-N3jHA

Comment: @Viewed Thank you, I hope your site is safe to use - anitvirus had no complaints. I should start archiving important API information like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of updating data for every character, we can update change on input blur event. Which will be triggered only after the input is blurred.

> So this only updates when the input is blurred (like when we click outside the input)

```
 function onBlur() {
        let data = {
            title: titleUserTab.value,
            url: urlUserTab.value,
        };
        saveOption('dataUserTab',data);
 }    
 titleUserTab.addEventListener('blur', onBlur);
 urlUserTab.addEventListener('blur', onBlur);
```

But if you want the data to be updated dynamically before the blur, it's better to use debounce. So when after every change we call save function with a delay, If a new change comes before the delay is over, the delay gets cancelled and it waits for the new delay to be completed. Which is something similar to your approach, but simpler as we don't need to clear the event listeners and add them frequently. The debounce function will be like this

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {

  var timeout;

  return function executedFunction() {
    var context = this;
    var args = arguments;

    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };

    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;

    clearTimeout(timeout);

    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);

    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};
function onBlur() {
    let data = {
        title: titleUserTab.value,
        url: urlUserTab.value,
    };
    saveOption('dataUserTab', data);
}
titleUserTab.addEventListener('input', debounce(onBlur, 1000));
urlUserTab.addEventListener('input', debounce(onBlur, 1000));
```

The above code waits for 1 second before updating the data.
[ref](https://gist.github.com/treyhuffine/2ced8b8c503e5246e2fd258ddbd21b8c#file-debounce-js)

We also can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce) library for debounce

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially promisify `chrome.storage.sync.set` then only create a new call the the storage API once it resolves.

Answer (score 0):

The idea sounds good, but you could instead use "setInterval" along with a "previous value" variable:

```js
var oldData = null;
setInterval(
  ()=>{
    var data = {
      title: titleUserTab.value,
      url: urlUserTab.value,
    };
    if (data!=oldData) {
      saveOption('dataUserTab', data);
    }
    oldData=data
  },
4000);
```